# Python & Agate : Inserting new rows only

Tags: python, postgresql

I am using [agate](http://agate.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.1/cookbook/basics.html) to load my csv file into Postgres.

```
table = agate.Table.from_csv(csvPath)
table.to_sql('postgresql:///Pricing', 'complete', )
```

Is there a way to only insert rows that do not already exist in Postgres?  The unique key would be ref & date

Comment: Could you insert all data in a temp table. Then load your final table using [upsert](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/upsert-records-with-postgresql-9-5)

Comment: This will be a daily import so I guess I could import the data and then dedup it